# OpenCV: Differentiate between two very similar contours

Tags: python, opencv

I use openCV to find contours in images.
The problem is, that some of the contours are just some artifacts I do not want to identify.
In the following image you see an example:
[image]

I am interested in the countours 20 and 21. 19 should be ignored.

UPDATE:
I am not interested in the size of the contours, the pixels within the contiour is what differntiates them.
here is another example:
[image]

Countour 18 is kindy blurry, has no "sharp contours" within it. Countour 16 has clearer edges and the colorintensity is focused in the center.
I would like to know if there is a way to identify contours like that?
I tried it with  blurry detection ([see here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/)) but the output between the multiple images was very very differnet...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: consider a higher threshold. your contours clearly delineate something but it's fainter/darker than what you appear to be interested in (the bright bits inside)

Answer (score 0):

after finding contours you can find the area of that individual contour and set a if else condition to select that contours

```
(contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(control, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
      area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            if (area > 200):
```

in a program i used that contours whose are more than 200 you can also use this